# Pos for .NET PosPrinter - Get dpi and/or max width

Tags: .net, thermal-printer, pos-for-.net

Is it possible to get pos printer's dpi, or max width in pixels, or paper width in mm trough PosPrinter class? I cannot find those properties anywhere.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the printer supports page mode (check `CapRecPageMode`), `PageModeArea` may be used to figure out the width in the desired units (set `MapMode` to choose the units).

If `CapRecPageMode` is false, use `RecLineWidth` (and `MapMode`) for the widest `RecLineChars` supported by your printer.